# Изменить значения массива

Tags: android, массивы, textview

Есть массив:

```
int[][] a = new int [50][50];
```

Затем я вывожу его в объект TextView (table):

```
StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
for(int ii = 0; ii <= pow(2,n); ii++){//strings of the truth table
    for(int jj = 1; jj <= pow(2,n); jj++){//rows...
        strBuild.append(a[ii][jj]);
        strBuild.append(" ");
    }
    strBuild.append("\n");
}

table.setText(strBuild.toString());
```

и получаю следующее:
Допустим, n=2( в программе определяется динамически):

```
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
```

А мне нужно получить:

```
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы вам кто то помог, потрудитесь оформить свой вопрос так, чтобы другим тоже стало понятно, что нужно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно указываете границы. Для 4х4:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < pow(2,n); ii++){//strings of the truth table
    for(int jj = 0; jj < pow(2,n); jj++){//rows...
        ...
```